Why does my website load bugged on iphones, even tho it works fine on androids?
I developed a calculator using react and it works fine on my pc, so i uploaded it to github pages. The page in my both friend's phone works fine, and they use android, but for some reason on my iphone it looks bugged.
the webpage on my iphone
Here is my .html file
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="./src/assets/171352_calculator_icon2.png"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

And here is my .css file. I am using vite and react, so i am not sure if i made it right, but it worked on  android phones. I send it to 4 differents friends with android and 2 iphones, and only the iphones were bugged.
#calculator{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    max-width: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#keys{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#display{
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    color:white;
    border: none;
    width: 340px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: end;
    font-size: 70px;

}

#keys-after-zero{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#zero-button{
    border-radius: 80px;
    width: 179px;
    text-align: start;
    padding-left: 34px;
}

button{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 31%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
}

button:active {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 41%);
}

.orange{
    background-color: hsl(35, 100%, 50%);
}

.orange:active{
    background-color: hsl(35, 100%, 40%);
}

.light-gray{
    color: #1C1C1C;
    background-color: hsl(60, 2%, 63%);
}

.light-gray:active{
    background-color: hsl(60, 2%, 53%);
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    #calculator{
        max-width: 280px;
    }

    button{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 27px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
    }

    #zero-button{
        width: 118px;
        padding-left: 34px;
    }

    #display {
        width: 225px;
        font-size: 55px;
        height: 60px;
    }
}

@media (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    #calculator{
        max-width: 280px;
    }

    button{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 27px;
    }

    #zero-button{
        width: 118px;
        padding-left: 34px;
    }

    #display {
        width: 225px;
        font-size: 55px;
        height: 60px;
    }
}


I tried change the css file, and i already made an @media in css to be different in cellphones and tried to add -webkit-appearance: none;, but it didn't work
If anyone wants to open the site and see how it looks, here is the link: https://edd-estevam.github.io/Calculator-react/
The repository is updated with the latest changes that i made: https://github.com/Edd-Estevam/Calculator-react
I tried to add some lines in css that i found in the internet, like @media (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){}, but it didn't work.

Well, i solved the problem. It was just the font size, so if you have the same problem that i did, you just need to decrease it to the point its not overflowing anymore.

As other answers has already mentioned. You are using plain CSS to render your application. Usually, if you use something like a UI library - it solves those issues inside ( don't know any specific React lib, but for example angular-material, paper ( for react native ) and i'm almost sure something like bootstrap etc. have those out of the box ).
I'm almsot 100% sure that you are facing default browser style issues - it is when a certain browser has a specific native style for each element ( if you place a button or input on android and ios it will look and behave a bit different )
If you wan't to stick to plain CSS i would suggest to use CSS reset (https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or something similar and i'm almost 100% sure it will solve your issue
